# how to display all tabs of a selected app from a dropdown in a vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
<apex:page controller="sampleConqq" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedApp}" multiselect="false" size="1">
     <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
         <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!incrementCounter}"  rerender="out1"/>
   </apex:selectList>
    <apex:pageBlock id="out1"> 
        <apex:pageBlockTable id="pgBlock" value="{!tabDescription}" var="v" rendered="!if(tabDescription.size>0,true,false)" > 
             <apex:column value="{!v}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>  
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

controller:

```
public class sampleConqq {

    public String tabSetDesc { get; set; }
    public list<String> tabNames {get; set;}
    public list<String> tabDesc  {get; set;}
    public list<String> tabDescription  {get; set;}
    public String selectedApp;
    public String getselectedApp() {
    return selectedApp;
    }

    public void setselectedApp(String selectedApp) {
        this.selectedApp = selectedApp;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
        List<AppMenuItem> apps=[SELECT Id,Label FROM AppMenuItem];
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('--None','--None--'));
        for(AppMenuItem a: apps)
        options.add(new selectoption(a.label,a.label));
        return options;
    }

     public pageReference incrementCounter(){
     system.debug('inside the incriment');
     system.debug('selected value'+selectedApp);
     list<String> tabNames= new List<String>(); 
     list<String> tabDescription =new List<String>();
     // Get tab set describes for each app
      List<Schema.DescribeTabSetResult> tabSetDesc = Schema.describeTabs();
    // Iterate through each tab set describe for each app and display the info
    if(tabSetDesc!=null && tabSetDesc.size()>0)
    for(DescribeTabSetResult tsr : tabSetDesc) {
    String appLabel = tsr.getLabel();
    tabNames.add(appLabel);
    System.debug('Label: ' + appLabel);

    if (appLabel == selectedApp) {
        List<Schema.DescribeTabResult> tabDesc = tsr.getTabs();
        System.debug('-- Tab information for the Selected app --');
        for(Schema.DescribeTabResult tr : tabDesc) {

            String TabLabel = tr.getLabel();
            System.debug('getLabel: ' + tr.getLabel());
            if(TabLabel!=null && !string.isempty(TabLabel))
            tabDescription.add(TabLabel);
         }
    }
}
   system.debug('tabNames for selected apps'+tabDescription.size());
   system.debug('tabNames'+tabNames.size());    
   return null;

     }   

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. Where exactly are you stuck? The more specific you are in your question, the better feedback you will get.

Comment: the below code dosent show output.<apex:pageBlock id="out1"> 
        <apex:pageBlockTable id="pgBlock" value="{!tabDescription}" var="v" rendered="!if(tabDescription.size>0,true,false)" > 
             <apex:column value="{!v}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>  
    </apex:pageBlock>

Comment: Are you getting the values in the debug statements in the end of incrementCounter method?

Comment: yes i get all the debugs perfectly. but somehow the vf page no output :( I dont understand why..?

Comment: system.debug('tabNames for selected apps'+tabDescription.size());  --->[51]|DEBUG|tabNames for selected apps11 system.debug('tabNames'+tabNames.size()); -->[52]|DEBUG|tabNames28